# How to configure MTM with TFS?

Tags: testing, tfs, automated-tests, mtm

I have several test cases in TFS. I would like to run those test cases using MTM(Microsoft test manager) automatically and update the test results. How to connect or configure MTM with TFS so that I can  automate all the test cases.

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380755(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Connecting TFS from MTM is easy, just enter the TFS name or URL and choose your team project:

[image]

Details of Automate a test case in Microsoft Test Manager, check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741(v=vs.120).aspx

If you use TFS 2015.2 and later versions, then it's not needed to use MTM, you can use new build system and Run Functional Tests task to executing automated tests, check: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/31/executing-automated-tests-in-build-vnext-using-test-plan-test-suites/

Comment: As of now I'm using TFS web version. I have set up the test agent(TA) and test controller(TC) in my laptop. TC has been set up successfully but TA is not connecting to TC. I'm using same AD credentials for both TA and TC configuration. Any inputs on how to setup TA & TC properly?

Comment: You can check this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546459(v=vs.120)

Comment: I have followed this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380741.aspx#link. My requirement is I have many test cases in TFS.To associate test method to test case we need to build each test project and check in to TFS everytime. Instead can we set up the project path which contains all the test methods once so that all the test cases can use it?

Comment: No, you can't set up the project path which contains all the test methods. But you can copy all build outputs for the test projects into drop folder, so that you don't need to check in to TFS everytime.

Comment: So that means for once we have to map each test cases to respective test methods , right?